# Kotlin - SQLITE (No suitable driver found)

Tags: sqlite, kotlin

I have been trying to use SQLite as my database manager but I am unable to resolve the problem where I am unable to get the program to recognise what driver to use.
this is the code I have for getting the connection to the database

```
package net.superfred.apps.sfam.utils

import java.sql.Connection
import java.sql.DriverManager

class Database(id: String) {

    private lateinit var con: Connection

    init {
        println("Database ID: $id")
    }

    fun connect(name: String, path: String) {
//        Class.forName(org.sqlite.JDBC)
        val url = "jdbc:sqlite:$path\\$name"
        con =  DriverManager.getConnection(url)
        println("${con.schema} schema is open")
    }
}
```

I have read up that i need to use this
   Class.forName(org.sqlite.JDBC)
However with kotlin, it causes the error: Classifier 'JDBC' does not have a companion object, and thus must be initialised here.
But I do not know what this means by this.
I have added the driver to my libraries and to the module dependencies using the IntelliJ settings to add libraries.

If anyone needs more information on what I am doing I will promptly respond with it.

Comment: I don't know if Kotlin is different, but in java, Class.forName() takes a string argument...

Comment: I noticed this but it still has the same error if I put in the string argument of "org.sqlite.JDBC"